# Path issues when opening a QFile

Tags: qt, path, qfile, qiodevice

In the following code I have an issue with file paths:

```
std::string fileName;
fileName = "/home/pietrom/default.json";          // ok
fileName = "file:///home/pietrom/default.json";   // error

QFile jsonFile;
jsonFile.setFileName(fileName.c_str());
jsonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
```

A path starting with "file://" is not recognized by `QFile::open`:

> QIODevice::read (QFile, "file:///home/pietrom/default.json"): device not open

The problem is that I get that format from a QML FileDialog.

Shall I just cut the "file://" token from the path, or is there a proper way to fix this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the problem ( I'm not really a QML user) but... are you looking for something like `QUrl` and, in particular, [`QUrl::toLocalFile`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qurl.html#toLocalFile)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use QUrl::toLocalPath ([here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qurl.html#toLocalFile)) to get the normal path

```
 QString fileName;
    fileName = "/home/pietrom/default.json";          // ok
    fileName = "file:///home/pietrom/default.json";   // should be OK as well

    QFile jsonFile;
    QUrl url(fileName);
    jsonFile.setFileName(url.toLocalFile());
    bool ok = jsonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    if (!ok){
            qDebug() << "Failed " <<  jsonFile.errorString() << "  " << jsonFile.fileName();
    }
    else
    {
            qDebug() << "OK" ;

    }
```